# Where does Magento 1.1.2 store the orders in DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, magento

I had a look into my cousins magento-DB and now I wonder, where does Magento store the user-ordersI searched all the tables but I can't find any order(?)

Comment: sales_flat_order is there?

Comment: no.. the last table is catalog_product_bundle_option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders are saved in tables: `(prefix)_sales_flat_order` and `(prefix)_sales_flat_order_item`

Comment: I do not have this tables ..oO

Comment: What version of Magento is your cousin running? PS - Run far away from Magento if you have a chance! haha (imho)

Comment: "Run far away from Magento".. thats what I have told him :D ..  can I somehow find out, what version it is? .. the problem is, that the frontend does not work anymore and he asked my if i could repair it.. so I opened the DB and now I am confused a.f. .. :/

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that if definitely required database tables are missing, the front end might disappear. I'd start that running now :) Either way, my answer is correct, so would appreciate the accept ;)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a working setup of Magento 1.1.2 installed but you may look in to following two tables.

```
sales_order
sales_order_entity
```